# Django URL dispatcher and lists?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm unsure if the title terminology makes much sense. But I have a pretty loose grasp on the URL dispatcher and if what I'm really asking here is in regards to the dispatcher or not really.

Here is my views file:

```
def current_game_table(request):
    items = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').all())

    # rest of your code
    return render(request, 'home/testing.html', {'items': items})

def your_details_view(request, pk):

    item = Nbav8.objects.using('totals').get(pk=pk)

    current_day_home_team = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').values_list('home_team_field', flat=True))
    current_day_away_team = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').values_list('away_team_field', flat=True))

    awayuyu = []
    homeuyu = []

    for team in current_day_home_team:
        home_team_list1 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.using('totals').filter(Q(away_team_field=team) | Q(home_team_field=team)).values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)

        homeuyu.append(list(home_team_list1[:5]))


    home_team_list2 = homeuyu

    typeitem = type(item)
    typehome = type(current_day_home_team)

    for team in current_day_away_team:
        away_team_list1 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.using('totals').filter(Q(away_team_field=team) | Q(home_team_field=team)).values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)
        away_teamdd = away_team_list1[:5]

        awayuyu.append(list(away_team_list1[:5]))


    away_team_list2 = awayuyu


    return render(request, 'home/testing2.html', {'item': item, 'away': away_team_list2, 'home': home_team_list2, 'type1': typeitem, 'type2': typehome, 'eep': current_day_home_team})
```

Here is my testing.html

```
Hello World

{{ items }}

{% for item in items %}
        <a href="{% url 'your_details_view' item.pk %}">{{ item.home_team_field }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is testing2.html

```
<p>The price of this item is: {{ item }}</p>
<p>The price of this item is: {{ home }}</p>
<p>The price of this item is: {{ away }}</p>


{{ eep }}


<a href="{% url 'your_details_view' item.pk %}">{{ away }}</a>
```

And here is my url page:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from apps.home import views

urlpatterns = [



    # The home page
    #path('', views.index, name='home'),


    # Matches any html file

    #path('charttest/', views.charttest, name='charts'),
    path('', views.nba, name='nba'),
    path('nbav2/', views.nba2, name='nba2'),
    path('nbav3/', views.nba3, name='nba3'),
    path('ncaa/', views.ncaa, name='ncaa'),
    path('nhl/', views.nhl, name='nhl'),
    path('testing/', views.current_game_table, name='testing'),
    path('your_details_view/<int:pk>', views.your_details_view, name='your_details_view')
  #  re_path(r'^.*\.*', views.pages, name='pages'),

]
```

```
class Nbav8(models.Model):
    home_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='HOME TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='AWAY TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Home Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    away_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Away Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    game_points_with_formula_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='GAME POINTS WITH FORMULA:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    game_money_line_field = models.FloatField(db_column='GAME MONEY LINE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    over_or_under = models.TextField(db_column='OVER OR UNDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'nbav8'

class PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg(models.Model):
    home_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='HOME TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='AWAY TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Home Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    away_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Away Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    game_points_with_formula_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='GAME POINTS WITH FORMULA:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    game_money_line_field = models.FloatField(db_column='GAME MONEY LINE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    over_or_under = models.TextField(db_column='OVER OR UNDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    actual_game_points_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ACTUAL GAME POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_points_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY TEAM POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_points_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME TEAM POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    actual_over_under_result_field = models.TextField(db_column='ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    percentage_won_field = models.FloatField(db_column='Percentage Won:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    win_or_lose_field = models.TextField(db_column='Win Or Lose:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_assists_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY ASSISTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_blocks_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY BLOCKS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_defensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY DEFENSiVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_effective_field_goal_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY EFFECTIVE FIELD GOAL %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_fg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FG %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_fg_attempts_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY FG ATTEMPTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_fico_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FICO:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_free_throw_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FREE THROW %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_free_throw_rate_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FREE THROW RATE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_offensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY OFFENSIVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_personal_fouls_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY PERSONAL FOULS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_points_per_game_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY POINTS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_steal_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY STEAL PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_3_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM 3%:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_opp_ppg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM OPP PPG:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_pace_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM PACE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_total_shot_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TOTAL SHOT PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_turnover_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY TURNOVER PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_turnover_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TURNOVER PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_assists_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME ASSISTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_blocks_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME BLOCKS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_defensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME DEFENSiVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_effective_field_goal_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME EFFECTIVE FIELD GOAL %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_fg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FG %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_fg_attempts_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME FG ATTEMPTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_fico_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FICO:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_free_throw_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FREE THROW %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_free_throw_rate_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FREE THROW RATE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_offensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME OFFENSIVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_personal_fouls_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME PERSONAL FOULS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_points_per_game_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME POINTS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_steal_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME STEAL PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_3_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM 3%:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_opp_ppg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM OPP PPG:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_pace_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM PACE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_total_shot_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TOTAL SHOT PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_turnover_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME TURNOVER PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_turnover_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TURNOVER PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    date_field = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg'
```

My question is, item in your_details_view is auto receiving the pk which is just an auto increment int. So as I click on each hyperlink from the main testing page, it takes me into the sub page of /your_details_view/1 for the first instance, /2 for the second, which is exactly what I want. I can also print out item in the testing2.html view which is displaying me 1,2,3 automatically on each sub html page. My question is..if I create a list in the "your_details_view" function, how can I iterate through it on each page automatically just like the the "item" increments? I tried this in my testing2.html page but it did not work like I had hoped it would

```
<p>The price of this item is: {{ item }}</p>
<p>The price of this item is: {{ home }}</p>
<p>The price of this item is: {{ away }}</p>


{{ eep }}


<a href="{% url 'your_details_view' item.pk %}">{{ away.pk }}</a>
```

I added .pk to that list or item but it did not make it index the pk like I was hoping?

Trying to add more context:

Say my main page "testing.html" iterates through a list of all the games that are on TV today. When I click the hyperlink into each specific game listed, I am bringing up a more in depth view of that game this is testing2.html. As you can see I'm also creating a few lists that have additional data that I would like to display on each page, but my problem is, each testing2.html page I only want to show one index of said list created in the your_details_view. So in this case, current_day_home_team is data I want to pass to test2.html, but I only want current_day_home_team[0] to show on /your_details_view/1, testing2.html page, I would want current_day_home_team[1] on the /your_details_view/2, testing2.html page. Again these pages are created after I click the hyperlink from the main testing.html page. Currently what happens is each more in depth game page that displays /your_details_view/1 - /your_details_view/10displays the entire current_day_home_team list and that is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer to the question is to generate the list on my backend py files and post to a DB, then grab from the DB table using pk as my index, I believe the work in my question should be done on the backend and not in the views file.

Answer (score 1):

It was kind of hard to understand your problem. But there's some things for you to try in order to find and solve your problem.

1. **The object `away` you return from your `your_details_view` is a list.** Lists or QuerySets do not carry a `pk` field. Only direct django Models have one. So the right way should be traversing that list with a for loop and access the pk field inside the loop. As you did in `testing.html`.
2. **Some of the QuerySets you construct inside `your_details_view` use the `values_list` function.** If you are going to need the `pk` field in your template, you must also include it in your `values_list` call. For example, in the list `away_team_list1` only the `actual_over_under_result_field` will be preserved, but not the `pk` field.

BTW... QuerySets are iterable, so you do not really need to explicitly cast it to list to traverse it on the template.

```
# no need to convert to list type 
items = list(Nbav8.objects.using('totals').all())
```

Comment: Thank you for that info, two things then. On number 1 -- in my testing.html I loop through the list and that is what I want, as I want to display the entire list content on one html page. My problem is, I only want to show index 1 of the away_team_list on sub page 1, and only show index 2 of away_team_list on sub page 2, not interate through the entire list, if that makes sense? on 2, I am not sure how I could include that pk field in the values list? I believe that may be exactly what I am looking to do as that would then follow the pk index through the pages for that list, correct?

Comment: Can you attach the related models to your question?

Comment: Added the two models I am using.

Comment: I also added some more info below the original question to try to better state my problem and what I'm looking to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe I would be told to do what I am attempting on what would be my backend? which is what I am going to do, I can create that data and post to a DB. I will then be able to grab it and use "item." to iterate through the list. I think this question was confusing because what I'm trying to do makes no sense :). Thanks for your replies and help.